# How Can I Streamline Modifications to Multiple Identical Excel Tables?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365, microsoft-excel-2016

We use Excel for Mac to track our business' daily services rendered. We have 31 identical tables on one worksheet, each of them for a single day. Another worksheet then totals the entire month's activities & generates various reports & charts.

Occasionally, we make changes to these Daily Input tables - for instance, adding a column for a new payment method and updating formulas in the table to include this new column. It's quite tedious to go through making several changes to all 31 tables. So my question is:

**Can I create some type of "template" table, where any changes would be populated into the 31 daily tables? Or is there any other way to make a set of identical changes to all these tables faster?**

*Edited to include Dropbox link to file:* [Dailies File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sz7txel5yiml046/Dailies_rev1.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: That sounds like awful data architecture. Instead of having 31 tables, use just one table and add a column for Date.

Comment: Thanks. This definitely seems like the simplest way to streamline any necessary changes, but we do use totals from each day's table - see edited post with Dropbox link to file. This gives us daily information rather than just a single total, and it makes it much quicker to identify mistakes.

Comment: You can use pivot tables to report daily totals.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the sheet tab for the sheet for day 1. 
Then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click on the sheet tab for the sheet for day 31. 
This will select all 31 sheets simultaneously:

[image: selected worksheet tabs]

Now, any worksheet changes you make will be applied to those 31 sheets.

Comment: Your tables are all on the same sheet. But it would probably be with the effort to move them to separate sheets so you could use Scott's solution.

Comment: Does this work with data tables? Once I select multiple tabs I don't have the option to modify the tables.  Also, our "Totals" sheet uses =SUMIF(!DailyD:D,"Total",!DailyF:F) to retrieve & sum all our totals - see edited post with Dropbox link. How would I replace that formula to retrieve data from all 31 tables on separate sheets?